# Help on Hpricot parsing html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use Hpricot to parse amazon mobile.website but I found that the source code I get from browser(IE, FF, Chrome and opera) is different from that parsed by Hpricot

for example:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0534243126](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534243126)

I am trying to extract the after-discount price. By looking at the source code from any browser, this is a very very easy job: doc.at("span[@class='dpOurPrice']").inner_text

However, it turns out open-uri/hpricot gets a completely different source code and the price has NO html tag on it. Could anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon mobile website server propabily uses the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string to determine what tipe of content to return and the user agent for ruby is not what the server expected. Set it with:

`open("http://xxx.com", 'User-Agent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2') { |f| Hpricot(f) }`

to by the same as the browser so that server returns the same source it would to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a different page because you're not passing a User-Agent HTTP Header along with your request. Try passing one along and see if that alters what you get back. (Hint: "Steal" Chrome's).

Next, I would not use Hpricot anymore as it is unmaintained and superseded by [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). With Nokogiri you would find this element using `doc.css("span.dpOurPrice")`, for instance.